# Looking for European dedicated server hosting provider

Tags: windows, dedicated-server

Our company is looking to deploy some servers in Europe, and given that were are in the US, our knowledge of overseas hosting facilities is limited.  We need dedicated servers that are in Spain, Italy, and Germany.  Can anyone recommend provider for any of these locations, better yet, any provider that maintains multiple data centers in 2-3 of these countries?

Edit:  I see some closed hits coming in - I posted this after seeing a similar question not closed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/190486/low-cost-shared-hosting-services-with-cron-facility-in-germany).  Maybe you want to vote to close that one too?

Answer (score 2):

OVH is the largest dedicated servers provider in Europe.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Equinix. They operate quite a few DCs.

Answer (score 0):

Do it all in Amsterdam, reach the countries you mentioned with low latency and IP's from the address pools of Spain, Italy and Germany. Best deal you can get on bandwidth by far.
http://webzilla.com/